# JSON Response is Undefined

Tags: php, json, undefined

I have a issue with JSON response. In am getting undefined values in JSON response. Here is my JS and PHP Code. I have tried every thing but still it giving me undefined value and when I try to console(response) then it displaying complete html.

Here is the Code Of JS and PHP

```
//Custom JS To Show Modal Update Box
function updateStudentShow($id){    
    $.ajax({
            method:"GET",
            url:"view.php",
            data:{id:$id},

            datatype:"JSON",
            success:function(data){
                $("#update_name").val(data.name);
                $("#update_about").val(data.des);
                alert(data.name);
                console.log(data);
            }   
    });
    $("#update").modal("show");
}


//PHP CODE

<?php
    include("connect.php");
    $response=array();
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $q="select * from student_details where id='$id'";
    }
    else{
        $q="select * from student_details";
    }
    $result_students=mysqli_query($con,$q);
    while($row_students=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_students)){

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $response=$row_students;
    }
    else{
    $id=$row_students['id'];
    $name=$row_students['name'];
    $des=$row_students['des'];
    $image=$row_students['image'];
?>


        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $des; ?></td>
            <td><img width="60" height="60" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></td>
            <td style="width:20%;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleteStudent(this.id)" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <span style="padding-right:10%;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="updateStudentShow(this.id)" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <span style="padding-right:10%;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                </a>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php } } ?>
<!--Loop Closed-->

<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $response=json_encode($response);
        echo $response;
    }
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_students)==0){ 
?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">No Records</td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Debug the request filtering by XHR http requests. Are you sure view.php is "hitted" by Ajax request?

Comment: Yes it is hitted.

Comment: There could be 15 reasons why it dont work, please organise your code into sections. You cant echo json if you've outputted html as it looks.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `json_encode()` on a table row. Notice up near the top of your html/php, you're doing `$row_students=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_students)` followed by `$response=$row_students;` and then at the bottom you're doing `$response=json_encode($response);`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for `json_encode()`, which says that the argument `value` that you pass to `json_endcode()` can be any type except a resource.

It then links you to the [appendix](http://php.net/manual/en/resource.php), where you can find out what counts as a resource. The response from `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is indeed a resource. It can't be passed to `json_encode()`.

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp) is an example that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting the data as html table before echoing your json response.

Your jquery is expecting json only.

To test the output of your script, simply visit the php script in a browser and add the id parameter
    http://host/.../view.php?id=1

Overall I think you need to split your code into two files.

- One that delivers the javascript and interface.
- One that delivers the data (json)

lets call the html output file view.php and the data output file data.php

view.php will contain the javascript which will use data.php in the ajax call to get its json data.

data.php will contain the code to retrieve records from the database and output them as json.

Comment: But will the html stuff which is in else condition will executed since $_Get[´id´] is set?

Comment: you're right, I didn't spot the 'if .. else..' around the html... you could get it to work. what is the output if you visit .../view.php?id=1 (assuming there is a record with id=1)? as I said, it would be easier if you split your code. Bear in mind that echoing even a blank line or a space will mess with code expecting json. php will send http headers as soon as you output any characters (e.g. the javascript at the start will be delivered as html).